# I am able to modify a constant string

Tags: c++

How come that output of following programm is "pankaj", I was expecting a compilation error like "can not modify a constant string"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(const char *a)
{
  a = "pankaj";
  cout  << a;
}

int main()
{
  const char *ptr = "GeeksforGeeks";
  fun(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't modify the *string* you modified the *pointer* that *points* to the *string* to make it point to a different *string*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re not modifying any string, just the parameter `a`.
First, it´s a pointer to the passed value, then it´s a pointer to a string constant in your program.
You can´t change the passed string data, but changing the pointer is fine.

Comment: how to change string data? you mean to say i can not do some thing like *a = 'm' , and pankaj will not be conveted to "mankaj"?

Comment: Yes you cannot do something like `*a = 'm'` as that would amount to changing a `const data`

Answer (score 2):

In C function parameters are passed by value. This means that inside `fun()` you're working with a copy of `a`, not the original variable. This means, that you're not modifying `ptr` inside `fun()`. Only it's copy stored locally in `a`. This variable, i.e. `a`, is not visible outside `fun()` and neither are any modifications made to it.

Now, `const char *a` means that `a` is a pointer that points to a location in memory containing read-only characters. This means, that you **cannot** modify those characters. You can, however, modify what `a` is pointing to and that's what you're doing.

Comment: Your first para is not really relevant as it is just fine to modify the original variable too

Comment: @MattMcNabb It's definitely less relevant than I originally thought it was. Thank you! I'll leave there though. It's already been up-voted in this form and this question is marked as [duplicate] anyway.

Answer (score 1):

ptr is a pointer to a char array.
The pointer is const, but not the content pointed by him.
U can change the content by doing:

```
ptr = "AnotherThing"
```

But You cannot change the memory direction the pointer is ponting to.

If you try this, you will get an error:

*ptr = 'C';

Comment: The pointer is not constant. The string that it's pointing to is. To be more precise: `const char * a` means that the character is constant, `char * const a` means that the pointer is constant.